# Limiting results returned from ViewResult to 10

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In my MVC 3 application I reference a database which then utilises the ViewResult method to display the results. I was wondering if there was a quick and simple way of limiting the output to only 10 results at a time as the database is large?

My code is included below:

```
    public ViewResult Details(int id)
    {
        Gap gap = db.Gaps.Find(id);
        return View(gap);
    }
```

Hopefully I'm on the right lines in editing the controller and not the view? Any help would be much appreciated.

Many thanks.

Chri3

Answer (score 1):

I agree that you are on the right lines editing the controller.  I am using the Entity Framework with Linq and using Skip and Take to control the results to 10 at a time.  My query was rather slow before because the table has over 20000 records and growing so I needed to only bring back 10 at a time.

```
LogListViewModel model = new LogListViewModel
        {
            Logs = _repository.Logs
            .OrderBy(p => p.Timestamp)
            .Skip((page - 1) * PageSize)
            .Take(PageSize),
            PagingInfo = new PagingInfo
            {
                CurrentPage = page,
                ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
                TotalItems = _repository.Logs.Count()
            }
        };
        return View(model);
```

Comment: This type of code shouldn't be in the controller, it should be in a data access class.

Comment: `_repository.Logs` returns DbSet of my object.  That is in my data access class.  This is just limiting the amount of records in my set in the controller.  Keeps everything nice and decoupled.